# Is there the autonomous transactions in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there the autonomous transactions in sqlite such as [in Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions)?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's autonomous transactions behave exactly like an independent transaction run through a separate connection. So just do that.

Comment: The autonomous transaction should be nested

Comment: What do you mean with that? What property of Oracle's autonomous transactions do you call "nested"?